# how to add textboxes dynamically to a table row in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, dynamically-generated

i want to add textboxes dynamically in C# on a button click in a table row. for that  i have used the following code.
         [1]: http://pastie.org/7702237.

the problem is i am able to adding as many textboxes as I want but they are adding at same location, i mean the table row is not incrementing for every button click instead it is simply replacing the old table row with the new one. Please help me in how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance
Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web-based applications do not maintain state; to this end the state of the table and any variables is not being maintained. With each postback (generated by the button), the table's state reverts to what it was prior to adding a row and then a row is programatically added to it.

In order to achieve your goal, you will need to maintain state somehow. In the following code snippet I am making use of a session:

```
private List<TableRow> TableRows
{
    get
    {
        if(Session["TableRows"] == null)
            Session["TableRows"] = new List<TableRow>();
        return (List<TableRow>)Session["TableRows"];
    }
}
```

The following is your code modified to work with the session variable:

```
TextBox txtE, txtM, txtB;
Button btnAdd, btnDel;

TableRow trow;
TableCell tcell;

foreach(TableRow tr in TableRows)
    tblEduDetails.Controls.Add(tr);

int count = TableRows.Count + 1;

txtE = new TextBox();
txtE.ID = "E" + count.ToString();
txtE.Visible = true;
txtE.Text = "E " + count.ToString();
txtE.BorderWidth = 2;
txtE.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
txtE.Height = 30;

txtM = new TextBox();
txtM.ID = "M" + count.ToString();
txtM.Visible = true;
txtM.Text = "M " + count.ToString();
txtM.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
txtM.Height = 30;

txtB = new TextBox();
txtB.ID = "E" + count.ToString();
txtB.Visible = true;
txtB.Text = "B " + count.ToString();
txtB.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
txtB.Height = 30;

btnAdd = new Button();
btnAdd.ID = "A" + count.ToString();

btnDel = new Button();
btnDel.ID = "D" + count.ToString();

trow = new TableRow();
trow.ID = "R" + count.ToString();
trow.BorderWidth = 1;

tcell = new TableCell();
tcell.ID = "E" + count.ToString();
tcell.Controls.Add(txtE);
trow.Controls.Add(tcell);

tcell = new TableCell();
tcell.ID = "B" + count.ToString();
tcell.Controls.Add(txtM);
trow.Controls.Add(tcell);

tcell = new TableCell();
tcell.ID = "M" + count.ToString();
tcell.Controls.Add(txtB);
trow.Controls.Add(tcell);

tblEduDetails.Controls.Add(trow);
TableRows.Add(trow);
```

Comment: This gives error for since TableRow is not Serialized, What can be done for it?